# Django Model/Database design for subclasses

Tags: python, django, database-design, django-models, django-admin

Ok, i'm shit at describing. Here's a relationship diag.
[image: relationship diag]

In Django i've made my models like:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

class Survey(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published',default=datetime.now)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

# This model should be abstracted by a more specific model
class Section(models.Model):
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

# Models for supporting the 'ratings' mode
class RatingSection(Section):
    pass

class RatingQuestion(models.Model):
    section = models.ForeignKey(RatingSection)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class RatingAnswer(models.Model):
    section = models.ForeignKey(RatingSection)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class RatingVotes(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(RatingQuestion)
    answer = models.ForeignKey(RatingAnswer)
    votes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.votes + self.answer.name + ' votes for ' + self.question.name

# Models for supporting the 'multichoice' mode
class MultiChoiceSection(Section):
    can_select_multiple = models.BooleanField()

class MultiChoiceQuestion(models.Model):
    section = models.ForeignKey(MultiChoiceSection)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class MultiChoiceAnswer(models.Model):
    section = models.ForeignKey(MultiChoiceSection)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    votes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

The problem is that I'm almost certain that's not the right way to do it, and even if it is, I can't work out how to allow the admin area in Django to display a selection to the user asking what sub-type of section they want.

What would be the best way to structure models of this sort?

Comment: Maybe you can describe a bit more detail what you need your "sections" for?

Comment: Idealy I'd like to have each Survey have multiple sections of different types (e.g. multiple choice or rating), and I wanted each different type to be a subclass of the generic class, Section. However, I'm not sure if this is the best database model - i'm pretty sure it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have one section class as well, having an attribute `type` that could either be rating or multiplechoice - which would be rendered in the admin then as select box.
But I think you should have a look at Django's possibility to create abstract models: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#id6

```
class Section(models.Model):
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True        # no db table created for this model

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class RatingSection(Section):
    pass

class MultiChoiceSection(Section):
    can_select_multiple = models.BooleanField()
```

Comment: how exactly would I implement that "type" attribute though. Ideally i'd like it to simply list all the subclasses of Section so I don't have to change type handling manually.

Comment: Well if you take my solution from above you just need to register a ModelAdmin for evey Section class, and then you'd have a seperate Section in the admin to edit instances of this class!
Or second solution: You have one class with an attribute `choices` that can either be "rating" or "multichoice", see http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/choices/ on how to implement field choices!